# Pyspark read 7z compressed file containing csv

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How to read 7z compressed file in Pyspark?

I tried creating data frame like below:

```
df = spark.read.csv("s3a://test-bucket/dev/test.7z", sep='|')
```

`df.show()` is showing the data like below -

```
+--------------------+
|                 _c0|
+--------------------+
|        7z��'��Ȥ�|
|$��...|
|Ӹ�<�Y[�0�O���!g���|
| jMi�,�K\T�@�ّ���...|
|o\�*l��vg'BS�s�...|
|I�N�t  ���Ni��?ޣ�...|
|V�!�?g`�]�%ޚ�i�V...|
|�����p �Bj*���mv...|
|              �>d�UH|
|�,i��e�k�z�)�Pj...|
|�����Mn���Eo�,...|
|�ux D���)6��^6�j...|
|�쥲���o�}�~S#N��...|
|6*�(au���9��Lq'2�...|
|]�R��J!6 a�m�c�i...|
|�H�_Ae1�P��} JZ��...|
|�z~O�@SG   �̬H��@...|
|+V`(/���D��Z� ...|
|ز����[�6�z��<:��...|
|                 NH�|
+--------------------+
```

Is 7z supported? Is there any way to read 7z?

Comment: Does `sc.textFile("s3a://test-bucket/dev/test.7z").toDF()` work?

Comment: No @pault Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely need to unzip the .7z file and then read in the unzipped underlying data files into the spark df.